# Какой паттерн используется в этом случае: Proxy или Decorator?

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования

Есть сервис, который реализует интерфейс. В методах он отправляет запросы внешнему api, получает ответ и возвращает его.
Второй сервис реализует тот же интерфейс, но при этом содержит в себе объект первого. Перед тем, как использовать методы первого сервиса (отправить запросы внешнему api) он проверяет, есть ли определенные файлы кеша, если нет, только тогда использует методы первого и отправляет ответ, при этом кэширует данные. Если есть, то методы первого сервиса не используются, а данные достаются из кэша.
Какой в данном случае используется паттерн Proxy или Decorator? Не могу точно понять.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152135/discussion-on-question-by--------proxy); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.